# Script Query for cosine similarity with vectors is not working in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

During Text similarity search, Script Query for cosine similarity with vectors is not working in Elasticsearch.
My Query is:

```
  Query="query": {"match_all": {}},
   "script": {"source": "cosineSimilarity(params.Query_vector, 'my_vector') + 1.0",
          "params": {"Query_vector": Query_vector}}}}
```

I am getting below error

---

```
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py in _raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    242 
    243         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
--> 244             status_code, error_message, additional_info
    245         )
    246 

RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

I can see its a transport error of Elasticsearch,I also tried to fix it through changing Elasticsearch.yml file in config folder of elasticsearch by

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

but elasticsearch stops running after it, so stillI have not found any solution for this error, please help